# Mysql so so slow between 2 query

Tags: mysql

We're are working on a view (multiple join in this view). And I have 2 query like that:

```
 1. select *
from v_investment_planning_ticket v
               where v.ticket_id in
                     (select ti.ticket_id from ticket_item ti where ti.status = 'SENT')
order by v.period_created desc;
 2. select *
from v_investment_planning_ticket v
where v.ticket_id in
      (select ti.ticket_id from ticket_item ti where ti.status = 'SENT')
  and (v.ticket_status in
       ('NEW', 'NOT_DEPOSIT_IN', 'CASH_NOT_ENOUGH', 'CASH_ENOUGH', 'EXPIRED_DEPOSIT', 'PENDING', 'PROCESSING',
        'EXPIRED', 'REJECTED', 'PARTIALLY_SUCCESSFUL', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED'))
order by v.period_created desc;
```

I can say that the meaning of 2 query is the same. But with the first one MYSQL take ~40seconds each time to query it. And the second one it only take ~0.7 second. And the difference is I add one more condition in 2nd query with ALL ticket status I have. Please tell me why when I do that it's so different. Thanks so much
2 explained query:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "<subquery2>",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": null,
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": null,
    "filtered": 100,
    "Extra": "Using temporary; Using filesort"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "tk",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ticket_investment_planning_id_fk,ticket_target_term_period_id_fk",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "<subquery2>.ticket_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100,
    "Extra": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "p",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,investment_planning_target_id_fk",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 12133,
    "filtered": 0.01,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "ttp",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 5,
    "filtered": 20,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "t",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "dgo_db.p.target_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100,
    "Extra": "Using index"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "select_type": "MATERIALIZED",
    "table": "ti",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "ticket_item_ticket_id_fk",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 42797,
    "filtered": 14.29,
    "Extra": "Using where"
  }
]
```

---

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "ti",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "ticket_item_ticket_id_fk",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 42797,
    "filtered": 14.29,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "tk",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ticket_investment_planning_id_fk,ticket_target_term_period_id_fk",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "dgo_db.ti.ticket_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 50,
    "Extra": "Using where; End temporary"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "ttp",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 5,
    "filtered": 20,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "p",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,investment_planning_target_id_fk",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "dgo_db.tk.investment_plan_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100,
    "Extra": "Using where"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "t",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "dgo_db.p.target_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100,
    "Extra": "Using index"
  }
]
```

---

```
v_investment_planning_ticket:
select `p`.`id`                      AS `plan_id`,
       `p`.`customer_id`             AS `customer_id`,
       `p`.`customer_name`           AS `customer_name`,
       `p`.`custody_code`            AS `custody_code`,
       `p`.`account_no`              AS `account_no`,
       `p`.`tag_text`                AS `tag_text`,
       `p`.`target_id`               AS `target_id`,
       `p`.`target_name`             AS `target_name`,
       `p`.`business_line_id`        AS `business_line_id`,
       `p`.`business_line_name`      AS `business_line_name`,
       `p`.`business_line_code`      AS `business_line_code`,
       `p`.`product_key`             AS `product_key`,
       `p`.`target_portfolio`        AS `target_portfolio`,
       `p`.`target_attribute`        AS `target_attribute`,
       `p`.`careby_id`               AS `careby_id`,
       `p`.`careby_name`             AS `careby_name`,
       `p`.`department_id`           AS `department_id`,
       `p`.`department_name`         AS `department_name`,
       `p`.`execution_method`        AS `execution_method`,
       `p`.`creator`                 AS `creator`,
       `tk`.`id`                     AS `ticket_id`,
       `tk`.`status`                 AS `ticket_status`,
       `tk`.`total_amount`           AS `total_amount`,
       `tk`.`total_quantity`         AS `total_quantity`,
       `tk`.`total_located_amount`   AS `total_located_amount`,
       `tk`.`total_located_quantity` AS `total_located_quantity`,
       `tk`.`careby_id`              AS `ticket_careby_id`,
       `ttp`.`id`                    AS `period_id`,
       `ttp`.`name`                  AS `period_name`,
       `ttp`.`year`                  AS `period_year`,
       `ttp`.`start_time`            AS `period_start_time`,
       `ttp`.`end_time`              AS `period_end_time`,
       `ttp`.`created`               AS `period_created`
from (((`dgo_db`.`investment_planning` `p` join `dgo_db`.`target` `t` on ((`p`.`target_id` = `t`.`id`))) join `dgo_db`.`ticket` `tk` on ((`p`.`id` = `tk`.`investment_plan_id`)))
         join `dgo_db`.`target_term_period` `ttp` on ((`ttp`.`id` = `tk`.`period_id`)));
```

---

```
create table ticket_item
(
    id                bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    ticket_id         bigint unsigned                                                                            not null,
    status            enum ('PENDING', 'PROCESSING', 'SENT', 'FILLED', 'PARTIALLY_FILLED', 'FAILED', 'REJECTED') not null,
    error_description varchar(255)                                                                               null,
    trading_date      date                                                                                       null,
    sec_type          varchar(50)                                                                                null,
    trans_ref         varchar(50)                                                                                null,
    code_id           varchar(50)                                                                                null,
    symbol            varchar(50)                                                                                null,
    product_id        varchar(100)                                                                               null,
    product_code      varchar(50)                                                                                null,
    quantity          decimal(12, 3)                                                                             null,
    amount            decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
    located_quantity  decimal(12, 3)                                                                             null,
    located_amount    decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
    price             decimal(15, 3)                                                                             null,
    rate              decimal(6, 3)                                                                              null,
    created           datetime                                                                                   not null,
    modified          timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                                                        null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint ticket_item_ticket_id_fk
        foreign key (ticket_id) references ticket (id)
);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: You might be better off asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas I hope that someone using JAVA + MYSQL have problem like me can help me :D

Comment: Java has nothing to do with the way different mysql commands sent from java would effect query speed. Also the two output JSON values aren't identical, seems like the queries are giving different results hence the difference in time?

Comment: @JaisonThomas yeah I know Java did nothing here. I just hope that more people can reach my question and give me some suggestion for it :D. The queries aren't giving different results bro. It give the same result with 11888 hits. And I can tell that 2 queries has the same meaning. I just plus one condition with full VALUE I have in system.

Comment: share schema of both tables here.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA already updated schema. But I already said my view join many table man.